# Issues related to grep command looping for multiple csv files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, python, csv

I made a for loop script as shown below,

```
for file in *.csv
do
grep raxA $file > new_${file}
done && 
mkdir raxA && mv new_* raxA &&
for file in *.csv
do
grep raxB $file > new_${file}
done && 
mkdir raxB && mv new_* raxB &&
for file in *.csv
do
grep raxC $file > new_${file}
done && 
mkdir raxC && mv new_* raxC
```

This script works when all the keywords found in the **csv** file, but it fails when any one of the keywords is missing from the **csv** files. Could you please help me to make this work, when **grep** specified keyword misses in the csv files.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
mkdir -p raxA raxB raxC &&
  awk '
    /raxA/ {print > ("raxA/new_"FILENAME)}
    /raxB/ {print > ("raxB/new_"FILENAME)}
    /raxC/ {print > ("raxC/new_"FILENAME)}' ./*.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is connecting the commands with an AND (`&&`) operator after the `grep` command. Note the exit status of `grep`!

From `man grep`:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> Normally  the  exit  status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.

With an exit status of 1, the following commands are not run. See `man bash`

> command1 && command2
>
> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero (success).

Further hints:

1. Your `for`-loops may be combined in one
2. The keywords could become a `for`-loop and be nested with the file loop
3. First create the directories and directly redirect the output there to skip the `mv`

Comment: Thank you @Fiximan for your information. I know that this script is having a problem, but I don't know how to make this script to serve my purpose. Is there any way out to fix this issue by manupulating the same.

Comment: Did you understand what `&&` does and why the script fails due to it?

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed the issue with your command, I'm giving you an alternative way of what you are doing with shell-loops [that should be avoided](/q/169716/72456).

with `awk` you can also do search for the patterns and split each pattern matched into multiple files.

```
awk '{ matched=match($0, /rax[ABC]/); };
     matched{ dirname=substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH);
              system("mkdir -p " dirname);
              print >(dirname"/new_"FILENAME);
              matched=0;
}' infile
```

see [`man awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) for the [`match()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-match_0028_0029-function), [`substr()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-substr_0028_0029-function), [`system()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-system_0028_0029-function) functions.

since your file seems it's a .csv, and you may wanted to looking for the patterns in a specific column rather than in a whole line, add `-F,` to the command (specifying the input file's field separator) and replace `$0` (representing the whole line in `awk`) with corresponding column number in .csv file, for example to match patterns in first column use `$1`, second column with `$2`, third with `$3`, so on.